# Magento 2: Validate error from review form on product page does not translate

Tags: magento2, localisation, review, input

The message 'Please select one of each of the ratings above.' is not translating, when you try to add a review without choosing the stars.

The form is located in the file `form.phtml`

```
vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates
```

And the validation error is shown like this

```
    <input
        type="radio"
        name="ratings[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_rating->getId() ?>]"
        id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
        value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>"
        class="radio"
        data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please select one of each of the ratings above.'}}"
        aria-labelledby="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label"
/>
```

I tried to change it with

```
data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required: <?php __('Please select one of each of the ratings above.') ?> }}"
```

But it's not working.

**How can I translate this validation error?**

Comment: Make sure, there is an entry in your translation csv file for your text ''Please select one of each of the ratings above.'

Comment: It's there, but it doesn't translate.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a default Magento 2.2 bug.

It should be fixed in the next release (Magento v 2.2.2).

As a temporary solution you could try creating your own validation class as suggested here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10474